# What is the purpose of attribute "population" in OpenLayer Features?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

In **feature** usage [example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html), there is 2 attributes called `population` and `rainfall`.

```
...
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]),
    name: 'Null Island',
    population: 4000,
    rainfall: 500
});
...
```

What does it means? I searched around and didn't find any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an example of adding generic properties to a feature that you can then use elsewhere. The example doesn't make it super obvious. In that example you could add another property called 'numberOfDonkeys' with a value of 20, and then you could use that in the click event that fires the popup.

Foe example, I can change the Feature to be this.

```
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]),
  name: 'Null Island',
  population: 4000,
  rainfall: 500,
  numberOfDonkeys: 20
});
```

And change the map click event to this.

```
// display popup on click
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature) {
        return feature;
      });
  if (feature) {
    var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    popup.setPosition(coordinates);
    $(element).popover({
      'placement': 'top',
      'html': true,
      'content': feature.get('name') + ' Pop: ' + feature.get('population') + ' Donkeys: ' + feature.get('numberOfDonkeys')
    });
    $(element).popover('show');
  } else {
    $(element).popover('destroy');
  }
});
```

And you'll see the Population and numberOfDonkeys attributes in the popup.

jsFiddle Example - https://jsfiddle.net/6vd5gtho/

Ultimately you don't *need* those attributes at all, you could get rid of them, they are just examples of where you *could* put attributes you wanted to reuse in this way.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean anything. Null Island is an imaginary feature with some attributes defined, that's all.

Comment: @panoet I live there and I can confirm we are not 4000